# How can I extension TextField class with the additional method

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I want to add new `unfocus()` method to `TextField` class from `'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field'`.

Currently, I found how to implement it throw casting to `any` type:

*in `app.ts`*

```ts
import { TextField } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';

(<any>TextField.prototype).unfocus = function () {
    this.dismissSoftInput();
    if (this.android) {
        this.android.clearFocus();
    }
};
```

*in `some-page.ts`*

```ts
export function onMainGridLayoutTap(args: EventData) {
    const mainGridLayout = <GridLayout>args.object;

    const emailTextField: TextField = mainGridLayout.getViewById("emailTextField");
    (<any>emailTextField).unfocus();
}
```

It's work, but it looks ugly.

How can I extension TextField class with the additional method (and left autocompletion works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use module augmentation, where you extend types in external modules:

```
import { TextField } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';

declare module 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field' {
    export interface TextField {
        unfocus(): void;
    }
}
TextField.prototype.unfocus = function (this: TextField) {
    this.dismissSoftInput();
    if (this.android) {
        this.android.clearFocus();
    }
};


export function onMainGridLayoutTap(args: EventData) {
    const mainGridLayout = <GridLayout>args.object;

    const emailTextField: TextField = mainGridLayout.getViewById("emailTextField");
    emailTextField.unfocus();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your solution does the job in my case. Thank you!

Comment: As I already wrote current solution works as expected. But how can I put this extending functionality in separate file and then execute it from main file to get extended `TextField` in all other places?

Comment: @ych you put it in a file and you import it as you would a module `import 'file'`. It was my undestading this was more a typing question ..

Comment: Titian Cernicova-Dragomir thank you one more time (really it was dummy question ☺️)! `import 'file'` do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to extend and use your own:

```
import { TextField } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';

export class Custom extends TextField {
 unfocus(){
   // 
 }
}
```

*Extension* is natural for classes. Mutation, not so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not suitable in my case, because of `TextField` instances created by framework from XML layout.